# Save work as xml or other file to access later

Tags: xml, file, save

For my group's software program I am trying to make a way for the work done thus far to be saved preferably on XML.

The work would include selection of image files, selection of boxes on this image, and the data that came out of it.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming you're using .NET) You might find [NHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate) to be an easy way to persist your application's data objects to a simple relational database like SQLlite.

Otherwise, you might just look into making your application data objects [serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx), and saving them to disk. This can get [complicated quickly](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Persistence_.aspx), though, so proceed with caution.

In Java, it's called Hibernate, Serialization is the same concept. In Python, serialization is called pickling. Etc, etc.